# Find the max/min element and index AFTER a certain index

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
myList = [10, 7, 11, 5, 8, 9, 6]
```

I want to find the max element and index AFTER the absolute minimum in the list. I've done it by making a new list with all elements from 5 onwards and then finding the max. But if it's possible, I want to do everything using the original list.

So, how do I find maximum value and index of it that occurs after the absolute minimum?

Comment: Would you consider using list slicing different from making a new list? Something like finding the index of the minimum as `i`, then doing `min(myList[i:])`?

Comment: @DavyM yes list slicing works too

Comment: @buttHurtBuddy Would you find the max of `[5, 8, 9, 6]` or `[8, 9, 6]`. Is the minimum inclusive?

Comment: Yes, the minimum is inclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(1) space:

```
myList = [10, 7, 11, 5, 8, 9, 6]

n = len(myList)
key = myList.__getitem__
imin = min(range(n), key=key)
imax = max(range(imin + 1, n), key=key)

print('maximum', myList[imax], 'is at index', imax)
```

Prints:

```
maximum 9 is at index 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
myList = [10, 7, 11, 5, 8, 9, 6]
min_index = myList.index(min(myList)) 
print(max(myList[min_index:]))
```

Output

```
9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
myList = [10, 7, 11, 5, 8, 9, 6]
abs_max = max(myList[myList.index(min(myList)):])
```

Output:

```
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
max(myList[myList.index(min(myList)):])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what the absolute minimum will be in advance, you're going to have to iterate over the entire list, in which case you might as well store your smallest and largest values in separate variables and then use `index` to find them if you really don't want to create a new list.

*edit: Sagun's answer is more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> myList = [10, 7, 11, 5, 8, 9, 6]
>>> min_index = min(enumerate(myList), key = itemgetter(1))[0] # or key = lambda x: x[1]
>>> max(myList[min_index:])
9
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that most functions which calls the builtin `min` and `max` functions will scan the list more than once, but less than twice: the first scan for min will scan the entire list, the second will scan part of the list. Also, beware of solutions which create slides of the list (hint: look for the colon (`:`) symbol. Creating slide is alright, unless the size of the list is large then performance will be affected.

My solution will scan the list once, does not create any sub-list:

```
def minmax(seq):
    min_value = max_value = seq[0]
    for element in seq:
        if element <= min_value:
            min_value = max_value = element
        elif element > max_value:
            max_value = element

    return min_value, max_value

print(minmax([10, 7, 11, 5, 8, 9, 6]))
```

Output:

```
(5, 9)
```

## Notes

- The algorithm is simple: during scan, if we see a new minimum (i.e. `element` that is smaller than the current `min_value`), we reset both `min_value` and `max_value`. If we see a new maximum, update it.
- This algorithm assume a list of at least one element. It will crash for empty list.